# Firestore firebase - Need to combine two queries

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having an issue while trying to get my requests documents. I have a request collection. In my UI I need to show all the requests that have not been created by my user and that I have not sent any offerings to those requests. I have been able to get all the requests that have not been created by my user, but once I have sent an offer to that request I need to filter it from my first results batch.

```
inal queryResult = await requestsRef
    .where('userId', isNotEqualTo: firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
    .where(‘city.name’, whereIn: user.cities)
    .where(
      Filter.and(
        Filter('profesion.name', whereIn: user.profesions),
        Filter(‘type’, isEqualTo: requestTypeEnum.approved.name),
      ),
    )
    // .where(“offeredBy”, whereNotIn: [firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid])
    .limit(5)
    .get();
```

"offeredBy" is an array of userIds. Which have already sent their offers to that request.

The commented code is what I am trying to achieve now but firestore is throwing an error

```
!hasIn': You cannot use 'whereIn' filters more than once
```

Which is correct because in the docs says exactly that. I do not understand how to combine my first query with a second query that holds the commented logic to obtain my desire results. If there is another approach please let me know, maybe I am addressing this in a bad way.

Comment: I'd suggest you get the data and write a sorting algorithm and add them to the list. I guess combine 2 queries can generate lots of issues and might not even work

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know what the exact challenge you're facing is. Since you mentioned you're trying to combine two queries together, I think this article will be helpful.

[combining two queries with RxFire](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/combine-queries-in-firebase-cloud-firestore-for-javascript-with-rxfire-6e07e95ca5b3)
You could look into this link too! It might be helpful.
[Combining multiple Firestore queries to get specific results (with pagination)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114416/combining-multiple-firestore-queries-to-get-specific-results-with-pagination)